# C++ convert iterator to pointer (and end() to nullptr)

Tags: c++, c++11

I frequently find myself in the situation where I want get a pointer to an object in a container (if it exists) or a `nullptr` if not.  This results in me needing to check whether an iterator is equal to `std::end(container)` and then either dereference the iterator or return `nullptr`.

For example:

```
std::map<int, bar> container;
...
// case 1: passing to a function that needs a pointer...
auto iter = container.find(5);
foo(iter != container.end() ? &(*iter) : nullptr);

// case 2: executing a branch if the pointer is valid
auto iter = container.find(5);
if (auto ptr = iter != container.end() ? &(*iter) : nullptr)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

I hate how I can't do these in one line because we need to reference `iter` twice, which results in introducing `iter` into the parent scope.

One way to do it without needing `iter` in the parent scope would be to use a lambda I guess (untested):

```
if (auto ptr = [&](container::iterator i){ return i == container.end() ? nullptr : &(*i); }(container.find(5)))
{
  //do stuff
}
```

But it seems very verbose.  Are there any other efficient ways to do this (using a single call of `find`)?

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class C, class L>
decltype(&*std::begin(std::declval<C>()))
as_ptr(C&&c, L&&f){
  auto it = std::forward<L>(f)();
  if (it==c.end()) return nullptr;
  return &*it;
}

auto* p = as_ptr(vec, [&]{return vec.find(x);});
```

Full adl on `begin` would be better.

This lets you run any algorithm on the container and get the pointer or null you want.

Comment: Isn't the `std::forward<L>(f)` too much? Does the invocation of `f` really change whether we see it as a lvalue or rvalue? After all, we're not passing `f` to another function which might take a `T&&`.

Comment: I can override `operator()&&` differently than `operator()&` -- it is rarely done, but when writing generic code, write it as perfectly as you can.  As an example, a future C++ could optimize `&&` invocations of lambdas to move captured state that is returned implicitly.

Comment: Ah, yes. I though about `member_methods() &&`, but apparently I was too tired at 3 AM to remember `operator()`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use some template functions, one for container with `key_type` (and thus a `find` member function), and another one in order to find values of their `value_type`, using `std::find`:

```
template <class Container>
typename Container::pointer find_as_ptr(Container& ctn, typename Container::key_type const & key ){
  auto iter = ctn.find(key);
  return iter == ctn.end() ? nullptr : &(*iter);
}

template <class Container>
typename Container::pointer find_as_ptr(Container& ctn, typename Container::value_type const & val ){
  auto iter = std::find(ctn.begin(), ctn.end(), val);
  return iter == ctn.end() ? nullptr : &(*iter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple getter?

```
template<class Container>
auto get_value(Container& c, typename Container::key_type x)
    -> decltype(*c.begin())*
{
    auto it = c.find(x);

    return (it != c.end())
        ? &*it;
        : nullptr;
}
```